# compare 2 values within a while read loop, one from stdout and one from file

Tags: bash, loops, syntax, while-loop

I have a `while read line` loop where i am assigning `$user` and `$quota` twhich are coming from `stdout` but i have also a file from another server where i am checking if `$user` is existing in this file, which is also containing the `$user`'s quota.

I need to compare the `$quota` value which i am getting in `stdout` with the value within the file.

example:

```
    zmsoap -z GetQuotaUsageRequest -v -u https://$sourceserver:7071/service/admin/soap/ |awk {'print $4" "$5'} | cut -d'"' -f2,4 | sed -r 's/["]+/ /g' | while read line

do {

        user1=`echo $line|cut -f1 -d " "`
        quota1=`echo $line|cut -f2 -d " "`

        echo "$user1 has $quota1 on $sourceserver"
        if grep -q "$user1" "$allremotequotasnew"; then

        echo "OK: $user1 is EXISTING on $destserver"

        else

        echo "ERROR: $user1 NOT FOUND on $destserver" && echo "Creating $user1 on $destserver now..."
        fi

        }
done
```

any ideas? thanksa lot in advance

Comment: What is the output of your script?  you need provide more details of your question.

Comment: `user1 has 5093390213 byte on server1.com
OK: user1 is EXISTING on server1.com` and so on. It is counter-checking if the `$user` is existing in the file. But i also need to check the quota of this user within the given file at the same time i am checking if the user is in the file

Comment: If you want $user and $quota at the same time. After `grep -p` to judge whether the user exist, then run grep without "-p" option to get the line containing user and parse the line to retrieve $user and $quota.

Comment: @gzh: to answer your question from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103071/bash-for-cycle-issue) deleted posting: `extension_array=("iso" "exe" "txt" "fdf"); OLDIFS="$IFS"; IFS=","; echo "${extension_array[*]}"; IFS="$OLDIFS"`

Comment: @gzh: so this means i can extract the whole line out of the file with grep? And then i could cut user and quota into new variables?

Comment: sorry, i am not sure how to check if the user is existing in the file and also to cut out the quota of the file for comparison with `$quota` at the same time. I get `$user` and `$quota` as output to `stdout` and i want to compare them with the line in the file in which `$user` is found. 

The file looks like: **user33 quota**

and i need to check if `$user` is existing in the file, and if so, then also cut out it's quota and then compare quota from the file with `$quota`

Hope i have explained it better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The file looks like: user33 quota and i need to check if $user is existing in the file, and if so, then also cut out it's quota

You can solve this question by  the following script clips.

```
grep "$user1" "$allremotequotasnew" > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
   echo "OK: $user1 is EXISTING on $destserver"
   dest_line=`grep "$user1" "$allremotequotasnew"`
   dest_user=`echo $dest_line|cut -f1 -d " "`
   dest_quota=`echo $dest_line|cut -f2 -d " "`
else
   echo "ERROR: $user1 NOT FOUND on $destserver"
fi
```

dest_user and dest_quota are what you want to get from file.

Comment: thank you very much gzh! this was what i needed. But you have made 2 little typos, you have posted `dest_line=grep grep "$user1" "$allremotequotasnew"` -> twice the grep and the `do` is not required in this example.

But again thanks a lot, you saved my day!

Comment: @esha, Thx, I modified my post.